# How to disable UISwipeGestureRecognizer when load a new view?

Tags: ios, xcode, gesture, swipe

in my viewDidLoad I set

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerU = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpDetected:)]; swipeRecognizerU.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp; [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerU];
```

when I load a new view through popup I need to disable that gesture

```
// show popup view
-(IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender
{
    MJDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
}
```

after popup view is dismissed, I need to set swipe gesture back.

```
// hide popup view
-(IBAction)hidePopup:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
}
```

how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is property named enabled for `UIGestureRecognizer`. Have you try this, it should be ok to disable your swipes:

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set delegate at here.

Ex :

```
swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
        swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        swipeleft.delegate = self;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```

Then add function

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {


    if ((touch.view == test[1]) || (touch.view == test[2]) || (touch.view == test[3])) {

        [gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
        [swipeleft setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];

        [gestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
        [swipeleft setEnabled:NO];



        return NO;

    }
    else
    {
        [gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
        [swipeleft setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

        [gestureRecognizer setEnabled:YES];
        [swipeleft setEnabled:YES];

    return YES;
    }
}
```

I think useful for you